# Symfony2 php functions

Tags: php, function, symfony, webserver, administrator

I deployed a Symfony2 application on my server and I wanted to disable some php functions but I don't know if I can or not.

But I can't find any informations.

Should I just try to disable a function and look Symfony reaction ?
Or do you know any list or informations about unused php functions in Symfony2 ?

Comment: Does anyone else (you don't trust) deploy their applications on that server? If not, why do you want to disable functions?

Comment: If someone manages to upload a script on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just try to disable a function and look Symfony reaction ?

No.

> Do you know any list or informations about unused php functions in Symfony2 ?

No such list is published.

---

I think you can safely disable functions which are usually under the control of the old PHP *safe mode*. As a contributor of Symfony 2, I might be able to ask more precisely to your question, if you give us some details about the functions you want to disable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, here is a list of functions i would disable :apache_child_terminate
apache_setenv
define_syslog_variables
eval
exec
dl
pfsockopen
fsockopen
ftp_connect
ftp_exec
ftp_get
ftp_login
ftp_nb_fput
ftp_put
ftp_raw
ftp_rawlist
highlight_file
ini_alter
ini_set
ini_get_all
ini_restore
mysql_pconnect
openlog
phpinfo
passthru
php_uname
popen
pclose
posix_getpwuid
posix_kill
posix_mkfifo
posix_setpgid
posix_setsid
posix_setuid
posix_uname
proc_close
proc_get_status
proc_nice
proc_open
proc_terminate
shell_exec
syslog
system
symlink
curl_exec
curl_multi_exec
show_source

Comment: The removal of these functions seems OK but some are required by the console script (if you use it).

Comment: Ok thanks, and yes, I use the console script, but in summary : I'd like to disable functions which could cause breaches in my server's security.

Comment: I could cause breaches only if you have untrusted PHP scripts on that server (as @KingCrunch said).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to disable functions and launch the Symfony2 test suite. And, why not, your application test suite ;)